# Gemfile is being loaded twice. Why? And how can I stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler, gemfile

My Gemfile appears to be loading twice. When I run bundle install I see...

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'


gem 'haml'                    # asset engine
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails',                  '= 3.1.1'
gem 'readable_exceptions'
gem 'sass-rails',             "= 3.1.4"  # asset engine
gem 'uglifier'                # asset engine
gem 'bundler',                ">= 1.0.18" # 1.0.18 is required for proper asset pipeline support
gem "rake", "=0.8.7"
gem "resque"
gem 'date_validator'
gem "typhoeus"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "scout_rails"
puts "Loading Gemfile"
```

output:

```
Loading Gemfile
Loading Gemfile
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1)
```

I believe this is causing problems in my development environment, where everything is being loaded twice. When I run my server with passenger standalone, I have strange logs such as:

development.log:

```
/app/models/facebook_application.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant APP_PROPERTIES
/app/models/facebook_application.rb:59: warning: already initialized constant ADJUSTABLE_MIGRATIONS
/app/models/facebook_application.rb:210: warning: already initialized constant MAX_TRIES
```

What kind of system problem could cause everything to be loaded twice?

I am:

- using RVM
- I have deleted all system ruby gems
- using bundler
- I have deleted .rvmrc files
- not using a gemset
- using ruby-1.9.2-p320
- using rails 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like there is a line after 
    gem 'scout-rails'
which says
    puts 'Loading Gemfile'

So maybe it's not that you're loading your Gemfile twice (which actually wouldn't be a problem  since we can bundle install all day without anything becoming broken), but it just looks like your are because you're putting a line that says it.

Comment: using a `puts` in the gemfile just does what it says, it outputs the string in the terminal... It does not request a reload of the Gemfile, which would be an endless loop...

Answer (score 0):

This is how Bundler does his job. It performs some checking in order to satisfy the existing dependencies. Bundler runs `Gemfile` in its own DSL in order to get a tree of the dependencies.

Double-requiring is prohibited at the Ruby level: the first `require` loads the file, the next calls return `false` indicating that this file is already at the party and no need to load it again. So I doubt that Bundler could cause your error.

And by the way, you don't have to use `bundle exec` with the `rails` command. A Rails Core Team member explains [here](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/12/27/bundle-exec-rails-executes-bundler-setup-3-times) why.

And by the way #2: `install` is the default `bundle`'s behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it's caused by `Dsl#eval_gemfile` being called twice starting from:

1. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/67320924db1f1910b17fae0a9268b02077874d26/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb#L60 (true when `@bundler_version >= Gem::Version.new("1.14")`)
2. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/67320924db1f1910b17fae0a9268b02077874d26/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb#L62

It does not mean your gems get loaded twice (as being said earlier, it's being taken care of Ruby's `require` implementation). But it is annoying when you try to print something informative from gemfile once.

If your issue was related to printing some info out once, then a workaround for it could be (in lack of a better one) putting:

```
if $YOUR_ONCE_CHECK.nil?
  puts "Doing it only once"
  $YOUR_ONCE_CHECK = true
end
```

I'll put the respective stack traces below for details:

```
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:47:in `eval_gemfile'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/plugin.rb:60:in `gemfile_install'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:60:in `run'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/settings.rb:143:in `temporary'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
bin/bundle:23:in `load'
bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

And the other call:

```
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:47:in `eval_gemfile'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:12:in `evaluate'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:34:in `build'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/settings.rb:143:in `temporary'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
gems/bundler-1.17.0/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
bin/bundle:23:in `load'
bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```